# List of favorite questions in the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, bookmarks

I have just installed the Stack Exchange app for Android. It looks pretty good so far. But what would be really great is possibility to bookmark questions for a later review.

I noticed a "favorite" button near a question, so this would work as a bookmarking, but currently I can't review favorite questions in the app.